# Access Violation on OpenGL functions, injected into existing context

Tags: c++, opengl, hook, access-violation, glew

I've been developing a hack for an older game adding shaders. The dll intercepts opengl calls and then modifies the rendering pipeline as needed. I use glew to load extension functions. For the first time, I am testing compiling and using the .dll on a computer different than the one I primarily developed on.

I've had a previous build of this dll that did work previously on this new machine, but now, when I've compiled the dll from a working source on this machine and attempt to use it, i receive access violations on many gl* function calls (`glGenTextures`, `glBindTexture`), that looks like:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0C941CA3 in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xD8EBE92C. occurred
```

To initialize glew, I call `glewInit` when I intercept the first `glSwapBuffers` call. AFAIK this tells me the context already exists, and the gl calls are being called after this init step. I have attempted this with `glewExperimental` enabled as well. When i receive these errors, I have no indication that glew is not initializing correctly (`glewInit() == GLEW_OK`)

Am I missing something about OpenGL/glew availability between machines?

The primary development machine which it was working correctly on has a Nvidia Geforce GTX 660ti, running on Windows 10, compiling with VS2015

The secondary development machine which it is failing on, has a "AMD FirePro M6100 FireGL V", running on Windows 7, compiling with VS2017

Comment: Whenever you think you have an issue between different machines it would be nice to provide more information on those.

Comment: @rbaleksandar thanks, I've added relevant details about the GPU's and OS's for both machines

Comment: It's a bad idea to depend on libraries that depend on OpenGL to hook/inject OpenGL.. Glew relies on OpenGL32.dll already. If the game is loading it, you are hooking it and glew is loading it, chances are that glew is loading your hooked library (unless you are hooking the functions and not the entire OpenGL library). Take a look at a library I wrote for hooking Runescape (an OpenGL game): https://github.com/Brandon-T/GLX/blob/master/OpenGL32/src/Hooks/Exports.cpp#L534

Comment: @Brandon thanks, i am hooking just the individual functions that I am interested in. not sure in this case why it would work from an older version of the dll compiled on a different machine, as well as work in all instances on the other machine. i'll look into your library for insight to avoid such conflicts